# Xcode 13 Previewing Crashing on New Macbook Pro , Monterey

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, preview

anyone else had an issue half way through working on a project the preview just stops working and starts giving these error messages in the screenshots :-

[image]

[image]

Laptop is brand new running all the latest Software. DRIVING ME CRAZY
Clicking on software update just takes you to settings and of course, everything is uptodate. Any Ideas?

Comment: :-) so you dont think another develeloper somewhere might be having the issue?   dh

Comment: OK, Xcode 13, but what's the exact version of MacOS, what's the deployment target set on your app, and which of the Xcode 13 releases are you using?